# Jquery facebox disabling button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable the fillin button and enable it later. I thought i could just remove the attr href and rel from the anchour and add them again when i want it enabled but it still works even after i remove the href and rel. It must initialise before they are removed

```
$('#fillin').fadeTo("fast", .5).removeAttr("href"); 
$('#fillin').fadeTo("fast", .5).removeAttr("rel");

$('#fillin').attr('href', '#info');
$('#fillin').attr('rel', 'facebox');



$('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
        loadingImage : 'images/loading.gif',
        closeImage   : 'images/closelabel.png'
      });

<a id="fillin" href="#info" rel="facebox"><img border="0" src="images/getprice.png"/></a>
```

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 0):

To disable:

```
$('#fillin').bind('click', false);
```

To reenable:

```
$('#fillin').unbind('click', false);
```

This may or may not work depending on how Facebox attaches it's event handlers.

Comment: Doesn't work as in, Facebox still fires? Try moving the disabling link before/after you initialize Facebox (i.e. opposite to how you just tested it.)

Comment: Yes - facebox still fires... i can't put it before the initialize as its added right at the very top as a script

Comment: Here is the actual stuff Michael http://offline.raileisure.com/ I want to disable the Get Prices button

Comment: Seems Facebook has namespaced its event handler. Try replacing `click` with `click.facebox`.

Comment: No :-( $('#fillin').bind('click.facebox', false); doesn't seem to stop it

Comment: Whoops. Didn't notice your latest comment. Just tried my above suggestion, which doesn't seem to work. Hmmm....

Comment: I'll play with it a little. My default suggestion would be to put a hidden `div` positioned over the button (with no click handler) that you can hide and show as needed, but obviously not the cleanest solution.

Comment: Yeah - if i couldn't find an answer i was just going to swap buttons with Divs but as you say its a nasty way of doing it really

Comment: You could try the Copy Events plugin here: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/copyEvents. Then copy the events to a jQuery object which is never displayed, and unbind click handlers. Then you can copy the events back later. I suspect this would work. May be vulnerable to breakage in future jQuery versions however.

Comment: Agreed. Or modifying Facebook to allow its triggers to abort events. Other than that...